# How to find information about London Buses facing disruption?

Tags: public-transport, buses, london

Recently, when travelling in London, several bus routes were facing disruption due to road closures. There were signs saying the buses were diverted.

The diversion was occurring near my desired stop. I want to view information regarding the new route so that I can know which diverted bus route will suit me best. How can I do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

TFL Bus Status Updates provide up-to-date information on any disruptions, saying what specific stop(s) are not being served and any new stop(s) that are being served as a replacement.

- https://tfl.gov.uk/bus/status/